# Pythonic way of Python subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inner-classes

I would like to organize my code in a way that allows me to define methods that can be categorized based on their purpose. My solutions uses subclasses in the following way:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Portfolio:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3]
        self.y = [4,6,2]

    class Plotting:

        def red(x_value,y_value):
            plt.scatter(x=x_value,y=y_value,color="red")
            plt.show()

        def green(x_value,y_value):
            plt.scatter(x=x_value,y=y_value,color="green")
            plt.show()

    class Analysis:

        def min_max_x(x_value):
            print([min(x_value),max(x_value)])

        def min_max_y(y_value):
            print([min(y_value), max(y_value)])

# Creates Portfolio object
pf = Portfolio()

# Plotting
pf.Plotting.red(x_value=pf.x,y_value=pf.y)
pf.Plotting.green(x_value=pf.x,y_value=pf.y)

# Analysis
pf.Analysis.min_max_x(x_value=pf.x)
pf.Analysis.min_max_y(y_value=pf.y)
```

Even though this works, I am not really satisfied for the following reasons:

- I have to pass an argument to the method (e.g. 'pf.x'). This seems to be not very pythonic since I am calling the method from 'pf'. Thus I basically access 'pf' twice.
- My actual code is much longer and this approach would require me to write every line of code in the 'Portfolio' class and thus in one single file. Way too difficult to navigate.

So, my very question is: How can we construct a class with methods that are organized in a thematic way (e.g. Plotting, Analysis etc.) like in my example but without having to pass in arguments. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that you you create instantiate the class with the information about the portfolio:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Plotting:
    def __init__(self, portfolio):
        self.portfolio = portfolio

    def red(self):
        plt.scatter(x=self.portfolio.x, y=self.portfolio.y, color="red")
        plt.show()

    def green(self):
        plt.scatter(x=self.portfolio.x, y=self.portfolio.y, color="green")
        plt.show()


class Analysis:
    def __init__(self, portfolio):
        self.portfolio = portfolio

    def min_max_x(self):
        print([min(self.portfolio.x), max(self.portfolio.x)])

    def min_max_y(self):
        print([min(self.portfolio.y), max(self.portfolio.y)])


class Portfolio:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1, 2, 3]
        self.y = [4, 6, 2]
        self.plotting = Plotting(self)
        self.analysis = Analysis(self)


# Creates Portfolio object
pf = Portfolio()

# Plotting
pf.plotting.red()
pf.plotting.green()

# Analysis
pf.analysis.min_max_x()
pf.analysis.min_max_y()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Megalng. It works well. I just wonder whether this is considered pythonic. Another option would be to do it in a modular way and then use something like this: portfoliomanagement.plotting.green(pf) where 'portfoliomanagement' would be the name of the package, 'plotting' would be a module and 'red' a function within that module. Would that be considered to be more pythonic?

Comment: @neptunhiker No, In my opinion not. Also it would behave the exact same as your current implementation.